# How to get DeclRefExpr from the block in Clang AST?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to check whether block (in Objective C) doesn't have self references within it's body. The ways I've tried are below.

First I tried to use `VisitBlockDecl`, get the `BlockDecl` body and iterate it to get `DeclRefExpr` from it by the following way:

```
bool VisitBlockDecl (BlockDecl *block) {

    CompoundStmt *blockBody = block->getCompoundBody();

    for (CompoundStmt::body_iterator i = blockBody->body_begin(), e = blockBody->body_end(); i != e; ++i) {

        if (Expr *expr = dyn_cast<Expr>(*i)) {

            Expr *ref = expr->IgnoreImpCasts();

            if (DeclRefExpr *dre = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(ref)) {
                printf("DeclRefExpr from CompoundStmt\n");

            }

        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

In this case I expected output `DeclRefExpr from CompoundStmt` for `DeclRefExpr` that are located inside `BlockDecl`. But it doesn't work.

Then I try other way and visit `DeclRefExpr` and use `ASTContext`. But in this case I don't know how can I get `DeclRefExpr` parents.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this task?

Here is the example of AST part:
[image: AST example]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can look into the ASTMatcher and use the DSL to get that node. useful links [ASTMatcherReference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) and the [tutorial](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you may check this?

```
   bool checkBlockContainStrongSelf(BlockDecl *node)
{
    bool result = false;
    for (BlockDecl::capture_const_iterator iterator = node->capture_begin() ; iterator != node->capture_end(); iterator ++)
    {
        ImplicitParamDecl *implicitParamDecl = dyn_cast_or_null<ImplicitParamDecl>(iterator->getVariable());
        if (implicitParamDecl && implicitParamDecl->getName() == "self") {
            if (implicitParamDecl->isARCPseudoStrong()) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }


    return result;
}
```